# Vertical Divider As Pseudo Element With CSS Grids

Tags: html, css, css-grid, pseudo-element

I am using CSS Grids. I have a requirement to have a vertical separator between two DIVs. However, the vertical separator needs to be smaller than the height of the actual DIVs, so I don't believe I can use the DIV's border.

```css
.content-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 750px 21px 550px;
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100px;
}

.divider {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block">test</div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="block">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works and I'm able to use the  `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` to control the divider's height.

Ideally, I'd prefer this divider to be a CSS pseudo element but I can't get this working in any way. Is this possible to achieve the desired result or must I stick with an actual element in the HTML code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remove the *divider* element and make `content:after` your *divider* by adding `grid-column: 2` and `grid-row: 1` to this *pseudo element* (forces it *into* the middle column).

See demo below:

```css
.content-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 750px 21px 550px;
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100px;
}

.content:after { /* Now a pseudo element */
  content: '';
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  grid-column: 2; /* ADDED */
  grid-row: 1; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block">test</div>
    <div class="block">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a *divider* after *each* `block` then you can have a `grid-gap` between each `block` and put an *absolutely* positioned *pseudo* element in that space - see demo below:

```css
.content-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 150px); /* CHANGED */
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 20px; /* ADDED */
}

.block {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

.block:after { /* ADDED */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  right: -10px; /* adjust this */
  height: 80%; /* adjust this */
}

.block:last-child:after { /* ADDED */
  display: none; /* Hide the divider for the last block */
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="block">test</div>
    <div class="block">test</div>
    <div class="block">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kukkaz Thanks for your answer. I probably wasn't clear in my OP but the divider needs to be between each `block` not each `content`. Also there could be three or four `blocks` in a `content` DIV. ashish singh's answer seems to match my requirements although I also like your approach had it suited me.

Comment: @JohnSteed check out the updated answer and let me know if this helped you, thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the user changes the window's width, the border won't be synchronized with the grid layout gap width. Your solution is not responsive at all. Borders will overflow the grid columns content. Using `vw` is better.

Answer (score 4):

one way to do it

```css
.content-container{
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;

}

.content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 75px  55px;
  margin:auto;
  grid-gap: 20px;

}

.block{
  background-color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.block:not(:last-child):after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: calc(100% + 9px) ;
  color:red;
  width: 2px;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: black;
}

.divider{
    content: '';
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-left:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
 <div class="content-container">
    <div class="content">

      <div class="block">
        test
      </div>

      <div class="block">
        test
      </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**The following is an amelioration of @kukkuz's answer.**

@kukkuz's answer is not responsive because his `right` property's value's expressed in `px` instead of `vw`. If the final user decreases or increases his browser's width, your vertical separators will move at a different rate than the grid layout's columns are resized. They won't be visually synchronized. Results: your separators would overflow your columns' content.

Solution: use `vw` instead of `px` for the `right` property of @kukkuz.

Comment: Is this not what the edit button is for?